# action bar is null when called from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an Activity that handles some tabs and some fragments which are the view of the tabs. Whenever I call an Activity method from my fragment, the actionbar variable inside my Activity class goes null.

One of my fragments calls a method thats located within Activity:

```
mainActivity.updateTabTitles(0, 5);
```

inside of Activity is:

```
private ActionBar actionBar; // nitialized inside of OnCreate() as actionBar = getActionBar();

public void updateTabTitles(int pageNum, int remaining) {
    String text = tabs[pageNum] + " (" + remaining + ")";

    actionBar.getTabAt(pageNum).setText(text); // actionBar is NULL? NullPointerException
}
```

Why is it that when my fragment calls my activity method, the actionbar is null, but never otherwise?

Activity Code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Pre-arrival Plan", "Primary Survey", "Secondary Survey"};

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    updateTabTitles(0, 12);
    updateTabTitles(1, 2);
    updateTabTitles(2, 14);
}

public void updateTabTitles(int pageNum, int remaining) {
    String text = tabs[pageNum] + " (" + remaining + ")";
    System.out.println(actionBar); // Null

    actionBar.getTabAt(pageNum).setText(text);
}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
```

};

Comment: How do you initialize Actionbar? One common mistake is use getSupportedActionbar() where you should use getactionbar() or vise-varsa

Comment: I use `actionBar = getActionBar();` thanks for the response. The weird thing is that actionBar is not null when I call `updateTabTitles()` from within the Activity, it's only null when called from a fragment.

Comment: where exactly do you initialize the actionbar

Comment: @Arlind Inside of OnCreate() within the Activity

Comment: show us the complete Activity code

Comment: @Arlind I edited it in

Comment: @Arlind Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Can you also show us fragment code that call Activity's method?

Comment: @Kazuki check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

To call the method on the container Activity from your Fragment you should do:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateTabTitles(0, 5);
```